# Do you think using original Japanese words is out of date?

Tags: words

The more I learn Japanese, the more I think Japanese is a subtype of English, now every Japanese Word are replaced by English words, some words I learned from textbook seems out of date.

For example, I learn wage in Japanese is 給料, but now nobody use this word. Instead, they use サラリー(salary). 
Red is 赤い in textbook, but now everybody use レッド（red). 赤い seems totally out of date.

So what is the meaning of learning original Japanese words If you can just katakanaize English words and use Japanese Grammar to put them together?

I can't understand why Japanese use English words to replace every word that already exists in Japanese.

You already have 赤い, why use レッド？

Comment: 赤い and 給料 aren’t that out of date are they?

Comment: @firuvi they're not. I can't remember the last time I heard someone say レッド when it wasn't part of some longer name or expression.

Comment: 「サラリー」は「サラリーマン」でしかあまり使われない気がしますね

Comment: `給料, but now nobody uses this word` -- はっ！？ ◎「はい、今月の給料です。」×「はい、今月のサラリーです。」`赤い seems totally out of date.` -- ◎「どうしたの、目が赤いよ。」×「どうしたの、目がレッドよ。」

Comment: Where did you get this idea from? Because if you've been Japan you won't think that this is true. Nobody replaces 給料 as サラリー except when one's talking about サラリーマン. Sure, we're using レッド in some contexts (such as color of cars/phones/laptops etc), but we didn't completely replaced it. This applies to many other loan words.

Answer (score -1):

For this subjective yet relatable question, you chose bad examples - so bad that people are now nitpicking on them rather then the main point. Perhaps this could've been avoided by using examples like "sweets" and "お菓子" or whatnot.

Your examples are still not wrong:

Go to a Toyota dealer and ask for your car to be painted 赤い色. They will correct you with a straight face: "You mean センシュアルレッドマイカ?". This example is caused by marketing and sales obviously.

Recently, human resource vendors use the word "レート" when they could've simply used "時給". This is because the Japanese are extra sensitive when it comes to wages, and they would rather use this term to feel comfortable for themselves.

However, the **opposite** phenomenon also occurs. Some group of people would say, for example, "隣国の飛翔体" when they could've just said the name of that country and "missile". They have their own good or bad reasons to over complicate things and create reports that look like Chinese documentation.

---

I've seen many Japanese complain about what you just said. I could say such diversity and acceptance of foreign words are the beauty of Japan, but that would be a lie because this isn't a Japanese specific thing. If you look at India, not only English words but the entire English language is being used everywhere. Treat this as a loss of culture or evolution of diversity - it's all about perspective.

From my experience, the marketing team and consultants tends to come up with fancy Katakana jargon, especially for a product's color options as you pointed out. Without any rationale or source to back this up, I assume one of the main reason is due to corporations trying to sound catchy to comply to their コーポレート部門が掲げるリーダーシップのビジョン及びポリシー.

Comment: Surely you don't think お菓子 is an "out of date" word that "nobody uses" right? That's the argument the OP made about the other words.

Comment: Yep, I surely don't think お菓子 is abandoned at all. But I don't think OP was truly believing in the extinction of 赤 or 給料. I hope not.

Comment: ごオピニアンはベリーにサンキュー

Comment: I think "opinion" may be replaced with フィードバック but I don't see オピニオン being used. As for とても and 感謝します, they show no signs of being replaced any time soon except for cases such as サンキューハザード.

Comment: @CN.hitori is this meant to be a comedy routine?